# Indexing PostgreSQL Hstore Keys

Tags: postgresql, hstore

Would someone provide a bit of insight into how I might index all `keys` of an hstore?

Example: I want to retrieve all entries from a table which contain a specific key:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE hstore_col ? 'MyKey'
```

The problem is that I need `all` keys to be indexed, not just a particular one. There are currently 300+ unique keys present, so creating an index for each and every key is not an option. Therefore, the following index declaration falls short, and this is where the challenge arises:

```
CREATE INDEX "my_index" ON table _col ((hstore_col->'MyKey'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get by with a gist or gin index on the column itself versus an index on every key, as both those index types have support for the `?` operator.

For example:

```
create index idx_my_table_gist_hstore_col
on my_table using gist (hstore_col)
;
```

Comment: testing, i'll get back with you shortly.

Comment: This query: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE hstore_col ? 'MyKey'` does not use an index when created based on your example: `CREATE INDEX "my_idx" ON my_table USING GIST(hstore_col)`

Comment: 1. "set enable_seqscan = false" and verify that the index is usable just not used. 1. How many rows of data do you have?

Comment: aha! my version of postgre (9.1) does not support ? on hstores, however testing on a 9.3 instance does work. bout time to migrate. thanks a bunch, sir!